# jQuery add Height to parent

Tags: jquery, css

I have 8 tabs ranging in all different heights. Each having a similar class, and the active tab having its own class.

How can i get the height of the active tab and add it as a style to its parent? (When a different tab becomes active, the new height needs to be added.)

The code below is an example of what im trying to get. Thanks.

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 1426px;">
  <div class="child"></div>         ( height: 2245px )
  <div class="child"></div>         ( height: 983px )
  <div class="child"></div>         ( height: 3004px )
  <div class="child active"></div>  ( height: 1426px )
  <div class="child"></div>         ( height: 1209px )
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#parent').height($('.active').height());
```

However, since the child is under the parent, you should probably do this instead:

```
$('#parent').height($('.active').outerHeight());
```

If you want to set the height when a new tab is selected, you have to put that line at the same place where you set the "active" class. It could look something like this:

```
$('#parent').find('.child').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('#parent').height($this.outerHeight());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var childHeight = $(".active", "#parent").height();
$("#parent").height(childHeight)
```

or in a one-liner

```
$("#parent").height( $(".active", "#parent").height() );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what i need. How can the parent div get the new height when a different tab is selected?

Comment: if the "tab" is one of the child divs, then you can do just trap the click on the dom element and set the height based on the code given

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
 var child_selected_height = $('div.child.active').css('height');
$('#parent').css('height', child_selected_height);
```

or more simple:

```
$('#parent').css('height', $('div.child.active').css('height'));
```